# download all files from s3 bucket including paging python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to download all my files from a s3 bucket this is the code I have:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                  aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                  aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY
                  )
key_list = s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)['Contents']
for key in key_list:
    s3.download_file(bucket_name, key['Key'], key['Key'])
```

but it downloads only the 1st page files...
how can I download all the files from all the pages?

Answer (score 0):

The code below create a list of all bucket objects.

```
  s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
  bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
  return [o.key for o in bucket.objects.all()]
```